# Execute User Function on Remote Server

Tags: fish

When I log into the server, I can execute a user defined command, `runfw` from `fish_user_key_bindings.fish` file it runs fine.  But when I try to execute

```
ssh user@myipaddress "cd ~/mydir; runfw"
```

It replies `unknown command "runfw`.  Of course I can source the key bindings in command like this:

```
ssh user@myipaddress "cd ~/mydir; source ~/.config/fish/functions/fish_user_key_bindings.fish; runfw"
```

The `runfw` works, but other issues occur.  So the question is, how can I remotely execute a command with fully loaded fish environment for the `user`?

Comment: why did you put the function in `fish_user_key_bindings.fish` and not `~/.config/fish/functions/runfw.fish`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When not running interactively, fish does not execute `fish_user_key_bindings`, which causes that file to not be sourced.

When you then try to run that function, it hasn't already been defined (by loading sourcing fish_user_key_bindings.fish), so fish tries sourcing "runfw.fish", which doesn't exist. So it can't find the function.

So either source fish_user_key_bindings manually, or put that function into its dedicated file called "runfw.fish".